# Can I have both original experimental research and systematic review in one paper?

Tags: publications, journals, medicine

serious question because I can't find the answer. I am currently doing an animal study, and I am preparing a manuscript about this. However, I am thinking of adding a second part to this paper by doing a systematic review also. Thus, to make it an article that has both original research and systematic review. The reason to do this is that there are some limitations of this animal study, and I think a systematic review can further back up the conclusion drew by the animal study. In another way, the systematic review has its limitation as well, and the conclusion drew from my animal study can back up the statement from the review. Kinda reciprocal relationship between these two and I feel it can make the quality of this paper better. So my question is if this is acceptable? I haven't seen a study that has part one about original experimental research and part two about a systematic review.

Comment: what i mean part one is like in the method section, part 1: our experiments part 2: we also did a systematic review

Comment: What is acceptable in a journal paper is up to the editor with advice from the reviewers.

Comment: @Buffy I wouldn't find any information from all targeted journals' instructions, most of the time I think these two are separated to the best of my knowledge

Comment: Write the review from the point of view of how it is necessary to show the context of the importance of your original research. In that process if you are ending up with a systematic review that's well and good. But writing a systematic review for the sake of a systematic review should be done as a separate paper as its a separate task. Remember the Editor has to weigh in the imprtance of contribution so as to accept or ask you to send it to a lower journal.....(contd.)

Comment: ..... If you are writing the systematic review for the sake of it, it is a confusion for the editor. Everybody will start writing a systematic review along with their research in all their papers if it improves chances of acceptance and it is not a good thing right?

Comment: @user102868 the reason is I don't think the review itself will be a good paper and I have no intention to send it to a crappy journal. I want to add a review section more like a supplemental to back up the conclusion and discussion drew from my original experiments. My mind process is this is like you are conducting two experiments in one paper but in this case one of the experiment is a systematic review. Does this make sense?

Comment: @YdZheng : What I mean is as long it is backing up the conclusion its fine and fine only to that extent. I mean one should not go beyond that. Don't use the word 'systematic review' in your paper. Just say "we briefly discuss the relevant background". I don't mean you are sending it to a "crappy" journal. Not at all. Many Good or even great journals accept systematic review papers.

Comment: @user102868 Ok thank you very much maybe I will avoid using the word systematic in my paper. You are right all journals in my field (I do surgery study) publish systematic review papers, I don't mean it is bad I was just saying if I wrote a systematic review along for this particular topic, it wouldn't be a great paper.

Answer (score 3):

Your paper should have a complete convincing argument leading to your conclusions. If as the author you think a (perhaps unusual) systematic review of the literature strengthens your argument in an important way then include it.

Perhaps you could make it somewhat shorter than systematic.

You could include a statement in the paper or a cover letter to the editor explaining briefly why this material is necessary.